# JSP support in Jetty 9.3

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jetty

I'm trying to upgrade embedded Jetty to the latest version (`9.3.2.v20150730` as of now) from an older release (`9.3.0.M1`). 
I'm using JSP and current maven dependency is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

However I can't find a new version for this dependency in [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-jsp%22).

Looks like they have not released new jetty-jsp artifacts after `9.3.0.M1` for Jetty 9.3. New versions for all other jetty-related artifacts are available.

What is the alternative I should use for JSP support with latest Jetty version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got the answer from jett-users mailing list. Updated dependency is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also, from jetty-announce list:

> The 9.2 release has switched to using the Apache version of Jasper for
>   JSP and JSTL.   Early releases of Jetty used these implementations,
>   but switched to Glassfish when it became the reference implementation.
>   However the Apache version is now more rigorously maintained and hence
>   we have switched back.  Currently we are using a slightly modified
>   version of 8.0.3, however our  modifications have been contributed
>   back to apache and have been accepted for their 8.0.9 release, so we
>   will soon switch to using a standard jar from Apache.

Apparently they have switched back to standard jar from Apache.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use Tomcat implementation coordinates directly?

Comment: @Michael-O Could I? I didn't know at the time I asked the question they have contributed their changes back to Apache. This is what I was suggested to use. I'm not sure why they have defined new maven artifact like this though.

Comment: You may try the default artifact and See how far you get. In this works,  simply update your answer.